# Can Json web token sign with public key?

Tags: cryptography, jwt

I saw that JWT can sign a JSON object with private key, and verified by a public key.

I am thinking that would it be possible to use JWT to sign the API request payload using JWT. 
However, instead of using the private key, I want to use the public key to sign the API request payload and verify it on server side with my private key. Would it be possible? As I see the library implemented JWT seems only sign with private key and verify by public key.

Isn't it impossible to sign with public key?

Thanks

Comment: Signing with a public key doesn't make sense because the public key is supposed to be available to everyone (it's called public). If anyone can sign something how do you want to attest that you've got some message from the correct person or machine? Perhaps you're looking for JSON Web Encryption (JWE). Can you describe your usage scenario? Why do you think signing with the public key helps you in any way?

Comment: *"Isn't it impossible to sign with public key?"* - The math behind RSA permits it, but this goes against the JWT specification, so no you won't find a JWT library that permits it.

Comment: @ArtjomB. oh! ya... You pointed out a point which I didn't think of. Actually I want to add an extra level security to making sure that the API are calling from my app only but no others. Therefore, I am thinking about signing the request which looks likely for JWT

Comment: No need to use JWT for that. Just add an API key (some symmetric token) to your app and API. This is easy to implement and has a similar security guarantee (no guarantee whatsoever) as your envisioned solution. The problem is that a user can always reverse engineer your app and extract a public key or an API key. What you should definitely do is to use public key pinning (I assume your API is accessible through HTTPS).

Answer (score 7):

Tricky question, but I'll do my best. JWT uses RSA underneath and in RSA *public* and *private key* are "interchangeable". In general *public* and *private keys* only get their meaning by how you handle them after generating.

The one that you send over e.g. unencrypted channels and is known to other parties is called "*public key*".
The one that you hide and never give to anyone is called "*private key*"

So it should be possible, to use the server's public key to encrypt something (like done in the JWT token process) and send it to the server. The server would need the corresponding private key to decrypt it.

(Be aware, that the "*servers public key*" by design is known to possible attackers, and every attacker would be in general be able to use it to generate those JWT tokens. I do not know your use case here to give you proper advice.)

The only pitfall here, is the actual implementation of JWT (of which I sadly don't have enough knowledge). JWT could add some additional data to one of the "keys" and call that whole object "*public*" or "*private key*", destroying the "interchangeability"... The only way would be to dig through the documentation of JWT (hoping to find something) or through the source code, or just try it out :/

If you try it out, then let the community know :)